# Pauli's exclusion principle?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle, spin-statistics

1. What is the idea behind Pauli s exclusion principle?
2. Why should an electron or any particle having non integral spin obey this principle?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the Pauli Exclusion Principle say about a superposition of spin states?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109437/)

Comment: See also: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31565/, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54674/, or http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11003