# Mathematical proof that Fermions are half-integer spin particles, and half-integer spin particles are Fermions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, fermions, spin-statistics

See: 
[Why must fermions be antisymmetric?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/207459/)

[What causes the Pauli exclusion principle (and why does spin 1/2 = fermion)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11003/)

It was said that all fermions were half integer spin particles and all half spin particles were fermions. The Griffiths's testbook said that it could be proved in relativistic quantum and was taken as axiom in non-relativistic theory.

My question was that:

1. Could you give me the complete proof that Fermions are half integer spin particles, and half integer spin particles are Fermions?
2. Is there a way to prove it without relativistic condition?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/354625/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17893/2451 and links therein.